# Handling quotes and spaces in filenames

Tags: python, shell, filenames, delimiter

I want to create a Python (3) script that passes files to a Linux shell program. Straightforward enough to do, but I'm not sure how to pass filenames that could contain single- or double-quotes and spaces to the shell. I would presumably need to delimit filenames in case they contain spaces.

I might consider a command string something like `f"wc -c '{filename}'"`, but that would break down if I encounter a filename containing a single quote. Likewise if I delimit with double-quotes and encounter a file containing those.

As something like `Bob's "special" file` would be a valid ext4 filename, how do I cope with all the possibilities?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: If you use the `subprocess` module, and pass your parameters as a list instead of a string, you can forget about this.  It handles the quoting for you.

Comment: It's not that it handles the quoting, it's that no quoting is necessary, because it bypasses the shell and it's the *shell* that requires quoting characters that have special meaning to the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tim Roberts mentioned in comments, you can use `subprocess` module to bypass this problem. Here is a short example (assuming you have a list of filenames) for passing a list of filenames to `wc -c`:

```py
from subprocess import run


# assuming you have got a list of filenames
filenames = ['test.py', "Bob's special file", 'test space.py']
for filename in filenames:
    run(['wc', '-c', filename])
```

By the way, if you want to use Python to get all filenames under one specific directory,
you might consider [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir).